# How to get the tab character instead of spaces?

Tags: discussion

See [Extract data and transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706715/extract-data-and-transpose-in-python) question. OP tries to extract some contents from a tab separated csv file. There is a tab exists between each column . I just  copied the OP's file contents  from the post and paste it to my file for testing. But I got spaces instead of tabs. So how I get the exact form of contents(*tab separated*) instead of spaces?

Answer (score 4):

To get to the raw post of a question, you take the url:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706715/the-title-as-text`

Change `questions` to `posts` and `the-title-as-text` to `revisions`.  This brings you to the post history, even if it only has one revision.  You can also get here by clicking on 'edit' if there are more than one revision.

Anways, once you are there ( https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26706715/revisions ) you can click 'source' which will bring you to a long funky name which in this case is:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/d9543826-5c65-4e92-bbe3-1536882657bd/view-source

This will be a page with only the source of the text.  Tabs are tabs. Spaces are spaces.  It always works (even on locked posts where there is no 'edit' link).

Answer (score 3):

You can get the raw data (plus the four leading code-formatting spaces, which you'll have to remove) by going into edit mode for the post and copying from there.